# Dynamically change android soft keyboard language setting?

Tags: android, localization, locale, android-2.1-eclair

I have some edit boxes in my app, some of them I will input English text, some of them I will input Spanish.

I'm using the standard android soft keyboard, however as my device locale is set to English, when I type Spanish in one of my "Spanish" edit boxes, the English corrective text/predictive text makes this difficult.

The only workaround I've found, is to go into the device settings and change the language over, but this is quite annoying.

Is there anyway I could have some kind of button, that when clicked would dynamically change the soft keyboards language setting? Is this exposed via any Intents?

Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to slide your finger across the spacebar on your keyboard to change languages.

Comment: Your answer does not satisfy the question @Paul

Answer (score 2):

> Is there anyway I could have some kind of button, that when clicked would dynamically change the soft keyboards language setting? Is this exposed via any Intents?

No, sorry.

However, you can use `textNoSuggestions` with your [`android:inputType`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3ainputType) attribute on the `EditText` to try to get rid of the suggestions.

Comment: Unfortunately this suggestion does not work with other keyboards (i.e, the Hacker's keyboard).

Comment: @LuisA.Florit: That is why I used the word "try". All of the attributes like `inputType` are hints, which an IME is welcome to honor or ignore.

Comment: I see. It is actually an annoying thing to have to keep switching properties in the keyboard, and to remember to come back. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In the main phone settings you can choose input languages and then you can swipe the space bar to switch.