# Android - Get List of supported Locales

Tags: java, android, locale

I have to implement `AutoComplete TextView` for all the supported `locales` of Android Device. I tried the following:

```
 public class AutoCompleteView extends Activity{

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, Locales);
    AutoCompleteTextView textView = (AutoCompleteTextView)
            findViewById(R.id.locale_list);
    textView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
static Locale[] locales = Locale.getAvailableLocales();
private static final String[] Locales = ;
}
```

I am able to get the locales using `Locale[]`. In the last line of code, How to parse that to `String[] Locales`.. Please help me friends....

Comment: It returns String as a Java object. I need string array of all the locales...

Comment: Why do you need a final String[]?

Comment: Cant u understand the code place above?? I am using AutoCompleteTextView for displaying list of locales...

Comment: @Aʌɐpɥɐuı Do you want country names or country like this [af, af_NA, af_ZA, am, am_ET, ar, ar_AE, ar_BH, ar_DZ, ar_EG, ar_IQ, ar_JO, ar_KW.. or country display names or language

Comment: The Locale.toString() will return a String, so I think you can use a loop to call it iteratively. But your "final" on the String[] makes it a little difficult.

Comment: @Pragnani i want list of languages...

Comment: @Aʌɐpɥɐuı Sorry for late reply.. I have posted the answer.. check it once

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sorry for late reply

Try this

```
  Locale[] locales = Locale.getAvailableLocales();
            ArrayList<String> localcountries=new ArrayList<String>();
            for(Locale l:locales)
            {
                localcountries.add(l.getDisplayLanguage().toString());
            }
    String[] languages=(String[]) localcountries.toArray(new String[localcountries.size()]);
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: thanks. It worked for me. One more question is Can i change dynamically the Soft keyboard based on selected locale? For example, i have selected French using above code in AutoComplete TextView. After selected french, Can i dynamically change the soft keyboard to french for next EditText box??? Cani acheive that??? Please help me...

Comment: @Aʌɐpɥɐuı There is not way AFAIK, Check this for reference   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6545734/dynamically-change-android-soft-keyboard-language-setting

Comment: @Aʌɐpɥɐuı How ever you can change the Locale to get the resources in specific language, check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2900023/change-language-programatically-in-android

Comment: Yes, i already found that but instead of changing manually, cant we do dynamically??

Comment: @Aʌɐpɥɐuı In same answer CommonsGuy(Mark Murphy) answered that, it is not possible.

Comment: In the second link which you have given, some guys says that the answers have worked for them but i tried the same. But keyboard is not changing

Comment: what i have done is created firstactivity with AutoCompleteTextView and Button. While clicking that button, i am passing the AutoCompleteTextView Value(that is selected language - Hindi) to another Activity. In the second Activity, i have editText and after loading the Activity, keyboard is not showing. Onclick of EditText the English(Default language) keyboard is showing. I have tried Alex Volovoy's answer and harikrishnan's answer.... but not working... What i have to do? I have declared the Second Activity in manifest as <activity android:name=".FinalScreen"/>.. Do i need to change anymore?

Comment: @Aʌɐpɥɐuı In the Activity Tag of manifest set this android:configChanges="locale" attribute

Comment: Ok. For now, I thought that there is no other way to achieve this...If u found some post, please let me know....