# How to get all locale that was supported in installed android keyboard?

Tags: android, keyboard, locale, ime

So I was developing a simple app where it support multiple language but I need to know what kind of locale that were installed in user keyboard so I can recommend some IME to user to download. The app is about learning language like duolingo so I need to know whether the installed keyboard support the language they want to learn or not.

Comment: I do not believe that there is an API for this.

Comment: For this you does not need any kind of api or any other things. It will depends on user device. How many languages will be supported by that device.

Comment: @Shubham currently: english, chinese, japan, france

Comment: @CommonsWare yeah I think I should agree with you that there is no API that can handle this because IME is another application. Maybe I need to make custom IME for this.

Answer (score 0):

In argument pass where you need to use the locale to get the device default locale in your android  application use this:
`Locale.getDefault()'

And to get whole list [locale listing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15759507/android-get-list-of-supported-locales)

Comment: by doing this they only get the current active language of the device they can't give all languages to them and they are looking for the all supported locale language by device.

Comment: Try this. Hopefully this will help:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15759507/android-get-list-of-supported-locales

Comment: What I want to get is the keyboard's locale, not the device. For example, your device default locale is en_US, but you can type using arabic or other non latin keyboard. I can get the current active language of the keyboard but not all supported language of the keyboard/IME

Comment: @AnchitGupta it's only get the current keyboard locale, not all installed language/locale of the keyboard

Answer (score 0):

Try this it may helps you:

```
Locale[] loc = Locale.getAvailableLocales();
        ArrayList<String> locallanguage = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (Locale l : loc) {
            locallanguage.add(l.getDisplayLanguage().toString());
            Log.i("TAG1", l.getDisplayLanguage().toString());
        }
        String[] languageslist = (String[]) locallanguage.toArray(new String[locallanguage.size()]);
```

Comment: accept my answer if it was what helped you. Thank you.

Comment: already tried that, it only get device locale, not keyboard (IME)