# Localization with strings.xml

Tags: android, localization

I want to change the locale within my app. I have several `strings.xml` file depending on various locales.Issue I am facing is the app locale gets updated but the strings like in title or tabs header doesn't gets updated depending on locale changed.

I have killed my app using `System.exit(0)` and manually restarted it but changes doesn't gets reflected. Please help.

```
Locale locale = new Locale(language);
    Locale.setDefault(locale);

    Resources res = context.getResources();
    Configuration config = new Configuration(res.getConfiguration());
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 17) {
        config.setLocale(locale);
        context = context.createConfigurationContext(config);
    } else {
        config.locale = locale;
        res.updateConfiguration(config, res.getDisplayMetrics());
    }

    res.updateConfiguration(config, res.getDisplayMetrics());
```

Comment: Share your code for change locale

Comment: Locale locale = new Locale(language);
        Locale.setDefault(locale);

        Resources res = context.getResources();
        Configuration config = new Configuration(res.getConfiguration());
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 17) {
            config.setLocale(locale);
            context = context.createConfigurationContext(config);
        } else {
            config.locale = locale;
            res.updateConfiguration(config, res.getDisplayMetrics());
        }

        res.updateConfiguration(config, res.getDisplayMetrics());

Comment: Share your code, by edit your question - not in a comment section.

Comment: Arcgate qa007, try my code, i am also using in the fragment, so it might help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use bellow code to change locale

```
public void setLocale(Context context, String language)
{
    Locale newLocale;

    switch (language)
    {
        case "UK":
            newLocale = Locale.UK;
            break;

        default:
            newLocale = Locale.US;
            break;
    }

    Locale.setDefault(newLocale);
    Configuration config = new Configuration();

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 17) {
        config.setLocale(newLocale);
    } else {
       config.locale = newLocale;
    }

    context.getResources().updateConfiguration(config, getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
}
```

**Note: You must use this code on create of MainActivity.**

To restart your App you can use this:

```
public void resetApp(Context context) {
    Intent intent = context.getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(getBaseContext().
    getPackageName());
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

[Java Supported Locales](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/java8locales-2095355.html)

[Android - Get List of supported Locales](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15760802/1442180)

Comment: I am trying to switch between US and UK locale

Comment: @Arcgateqa007 You must use this code on create of MainActivity.

Comment: I have a fragment in which switching happens between locale. From there i am saving it in shared Preference and killing the app. Now in MainActivity i am picking the locale language from shared preference and have added your above code. Shall i restart the app again ?

Comment: @Arcgateqa007 I edit my answer and add a method to reset app. I hope it's useful

Comment: Thanks a lot it worked. It consumed my lot of time. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Write one util file for localization language :

```
public class LocaleUtil {

public static Configuration onAttach(Context context) {
    String lang = SessionSharedPrefs.getInstance().getLanguage();
    if (lang == null || lang.isEmpty()) {
        lang = "en";
    }
    return setLocale(context, lang);
}

public static Configuration setLocale(Context context, String language) {
    return updateResourcesLegacy(context, language);
}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
private static Configuration updateResourcesLegacy(Context context, String language) {
    Locale locale = new Locale(language);
    Locale.setDefault(locale);

    Resources resources = context.getResources();

    Configuration configuration = resources.getConfiguration();
    configuration.locale = locale;

    resources.updateConfiguration(configuration, resources.getDisplayMetrics());

    return configuration;
}
}
```

You can use this class util like:

```
//language should be in language code like "en", "te";
android.content.res.Configuration configuration = LocaleUtil.setLocale(getActivity(), language);
onConfigurationChanged(configuration);
```